# Lowering footnote positioning but keeping main text the same

Tags: header-footer, footnotes, margins

Very new to Latex but I have been searching these forums for a long time and could not find a solution to this problem. Here is a minimal sample page to illustrate my problem:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

This is some\footnote{This is a footnote} text.
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

If we inspect the footnote, you can see that there is a lot of space between it and the bottom of the page.

[image: Screenshot of sample page]

I would like to move the footnote lower down, *without affecting the rest of the text*. Ideally, it would look like this:

[image]

So far I have tried to make the footnotes stick with `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` but this does note reduce the huge bottom margin - it only forces the footnote to the bottom of the area if there is not enough text above it.

I have also tried to manually decrease the footer height while padding the footnote-to-text space, with these commands:

```
\usepackage[bottom=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1in}
```

Which gives the desired effect but has the unfortunate side-effect of shifting the main text down on pages without footnotes (as well as messing up all the margins...).

The `\footskip` command has also not yielded the desired results and I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Try with `\flushbottom` tag which should place after `\begin{document}`

Comment: With additional, give some vertical `glue` in your `\footskip` tag, i.e., `\setlength{\skip\footins}{1in plus1pt}`

Comment: @MadyYuvi Hello. I've tried these commands but they change the main text not the footnote itself. Thanks.

Comment: On pages without a footnote there is a lot of space below the text. The footnote is typeset within the typeblock. To be consistent increase the height of the typeblock if you don't like all the space below it.

Comment: @PeterWilson "The footnote is typeset within the typeblock" I see, this is the source of the problem them. If I increase \textheight so that footnotes are lower down I also affect the text area on pages without footnotes (which I don't want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't like what you are trying to do as the space below the main text should be consistent. However, for your particular example (I haven't tried to tidy up my code)

```
% footnoteprob.tex  SE 564168
\documentclass[]{article}

%\setlength{\footskip}{1in}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{plain}

%\setlength{\footskip}{1in}
%\setlength{\footins}{1in}

%\setlength{\footnotesep}{1in}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%
  \vspace{1in}
  \kern-3pt
  \hrule width 0.4\columnwidth
  \kern 2.6pt}
  
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
The \verb!\skip\footins! is \the\skip\footins
%\setlength{\skip\footins}{1in}

The footskip is \the\footskip

\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}
This is some\footnote{This is a footnote} text.
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I have changed the placement of the `\footnoterule` and increased the textheight to take account of the footnote being moved below the textblock leaving a couple of blank lines behind.

Do you really want to screw up LaTeX's typesetting paradigm?

Comment: Thanks for the solution Peter, and I appreciate the advice. My reason for wanting this is that I have a lot of footnotes and I don't like how they take up the main text space (since reading them is optional, I'd prefer them tucked away).  However, I will reconsider since in your experience this is a bad design choice.

Comment: @Frostbitten If you want them tucked away consider using endnotes instead. See the `endnotes` package. The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report`, `article`) lets you change footnotes into endnotes.